# Incrementing Number beside MySQL results?

Tags: php, increment

This is code from my PHP Script:

```
while($runrows = mysql_fetch_array($getquery)) //fetching results
{
$id = $runrows ['ID'];
$answer = $runrows ['Answer']; 
$category = $runrows ['Category']; 
$num = $runrows ['Question #']; 
$difficulty = $runrows ['Difficulty'];  
$question = $runrows ['Question']; 
$round = $runrows ['Round'];  
$tournament = $runrows ['Tournament'];  
$year = $runrows ['Year'];  
$a = 1;


//what will be displayed on the results page 
echo "
<div>$a</div>
<div class='alert alert-info' style='border-radius: 20px'>
<div style='padding: 10px; span5'>
<span class='label label-info' font-size='30px'><em>Tournament | Year | Round | Question # | Category</em></span><span style='margin-left: 500px; text-align: right'>ID: $id</span></div>
<b>$tournament |</b> <b>$year |</b> <b>$round |</b> <b>$num |</b> <b>$category</b>
<p><em>Question:</em> $question</p>
<div class='row'><div class='alert alert-info span7'><em><strong>ANSWER:</strong></em> $answer </div><div class='alert alert-info span2' align='right'>
<a href='#errorReportmodel' class='btn btn-inverse' data-toggle='modal'>Report an Error</a></div></div></div><hr>
";

}
```

How would I edit this code so that $a increments by 1 for each result. I want the number "1" to be beside result 1 and the number "2" to be beside result 2, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try initializing the `$a` variable outside the while loop, so it can be easily manipulated without being reset:

```
$a = 1;
while($runrows = mysql_fetch_array($getquery)) //fetching results
{
$id = $runrows ['ID'];
$answer = $runrows ['Answer']; 
$category = $runrows ['Category']; 
$num = $runrows ['Question #']; 
$difficulty = $runrows ['Difficulty'];  
$question = $runrows ['Question']; 
$round = $runrows ['Round'];  
$tournament = $runrows ['Tournament'];  
$year = $runrows ['Year'];  



//what will be displayed on the results page 
echo "
<div>$a</div>
<div class='alert alert-info' style='border-radius: 20px'>
<div style='padding: 10px; span5'>
<span class='label label-info' font-size='30px'><em>Tournament | Year | Round | Question # | Category</em></span><span style='margin-left: 500px; text-align: right'>ID: $id</span></div>
<b>$tournament |</b> <b>$year |</b> <b>$round |</b> <b>$num |</b> <b>$category</b>
<p><em>Question:</em> $question</p>
<div class='row'><div class='alert alert-info span7'><em><strong>ANSWER:</strong></em> $answer </div><div class='alert alert-info span2' align='right'>
<a href='#errorReportmodel' class='btn btn-inverse' data-toggle='modal'>Report an Error</a></div></div></div><hr>
";

}
```

Then use the `$a++` to increment the previous integer by one.. An example usage would be:

```
echo "
<div>$a</div>
<div class='alert alert-info' style='border-radius: 20px'>
<div style='padding: 10px; span5'>
<span class='label label-info' font-size='30px'><em>Tournament | Year | Round | Question # | Category</em></span><span style='margin-left: 500px; text-align: right'>ID: $id</span></div>
<b>$tournament |</b> <b>$year |</b> <b>$round |</b> <b>$num |</b> <b>$category</b>
<p><em>Question:</em> $question</p>
<div class='row'><div class='alert alert-info span7'><em><strong>ANSWER:</strong></em> $answer </div><div class='alert alert-info span2' align='right'>
<a href='#errorReportmodel' class='btn btn-inverse' data-toggle='modal'>Report an Error</a></div></div></div><hr>
";
  $a++; // Added here, so the contents of $a will be echoed prior to adding one. 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$a=1;
while($runrows = mysql_fetch_array($getquery)) {
//YOUR CODE
$a++;
}
```